# C++ malloc invalid conversion from `void*' to struct

Tags: c++, c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

When I try to `malloc()` a `struct bstree` node, my compiler is reporting an error:

> invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'bstree*'

Here is my code:

```cpp
struct bstree {
    int key;
    char *value;

    struct bstree *left;
    struct bstree *right;
};

struct bstree *bstree_create(int key, char *value) {
    struct bstree *node;

    node = malloc(sizeof (*node));

    if (node != NULL) {
        node->key = key;
        node->value = value;
        node->left = NULL;
        node->right = NULL;
    }
    return node;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to compile a C code with C++ compiler?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In C++ there is no implicit conversion from type `void *` to pointer of other type. You have to specify explicit casting. For example

```
node = ( struct bstree * )malloc(sizeof (*node));
```

or

```
node = static_cast<struct bstree *>( malloc(sizeof (*node)) );
```

Also in C++ you should use operator `new` instead of the C function `malloc`.

Comment: In C++ OP should not use `struct` in given context.

Comment: @SergeyA Why not to use an elaborated name? I do not see any reason for this.

Comment: @SergeyA I have not understood what you said. I do not see any "noise". I see a self-documentation.

Comment: There is no self-documentation. (struct bstree*) is the same thing as (bstree*) from compiler viewpoint, and does not add any information to the human reader, yet it is 7 characters longer. Hence it's syntaxic noise.

Comment: @SergeyA The project can contain C and C++ modules. The declaration of the structure can have C linkage language and is placed in a C header. bstree can be a typedef or it can be a non-aggregate class insetad of an aggregate and so on .

Comment: @SergeyA And by the way the function itself can be defined in a C module.:)

Comment: No, it can't - there would be no compiler error if it would be **defined** in C-module. And it doesn't matter which linkage struct declaration has - `struct` is still not neccessary in C++ cast code.

Comment: @SergeyA The module and the declaration can be used eitrher in C or C++ project. As the author does use preprocessor directives like #ifdef __cplusplus then it is desirable to make the code compiled by the both compilers C and C++.

Comment: @SergeyA I am sorry but for me  it is entirely uninteresting that some line of code can be reduced by 7 characters.

Comment: A misguided approach. The code should not be compiled by both compilers - you will end up using only a subset of features of both languages, which will make code uglier than it should be.

Comment: @SergeyA You efforts to reduce  the code by 7 characters does not make any sense. I shwoed a valid code.

Comment: @jxh, oh! I can do it too! It's just not there until I highlight my comment, so I thought I can't :)

Answer (score 2):

In C, your code is "fine".

In C++, you want to define a constructor:

```
struct bstree {
    int key;
    char *value;

    bstree *left;
    bstree *right;

    bstree (int k, char *v)
        : key(k), value(v), left(NULL), right(NULL)
    {}
};
```

And then use `new`, e.g.: `node = new bstree(key, value);`.

Comment: In C++ you do not want `struct bstree* left`.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it, but it is superfluous in this context.

Answer (score 0):

A cast would fix this error:

```
node = (struct bstree *) malloc(sizeof (*node));
```

I have shown a C-style cast since the code appears to be C.  There is also a C++-style cast:

```
node = static_cast<struct bstree *>(malloc(sizeof (*node)));
```

Comment: Why do you use `struct` in cast context in C++?

Comment: @SergeyA: In C, a structure type name must be prefixed with the `struct` keyword in declarations and type casts.  The `struct` keyword is optional in C++.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, yes, I know this. But, we (kinda) established OP is using C++ here. So what would be the point here?

Comment: In C++ there should be no cast at all